# How to apply value_counts(normalize=True) and value_counts() to pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I like to show the `value_counts(normalize=True)` of a `series` what works well, but I also wanna show the `value_counts()` not normalized in an additional column.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [32000,35000,37000,45000]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])

df.Brand.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

**Expected output**

```
                  perc   count
Toyota Corolla    0.25   1
Audi A4           0.25   1
Honda Civic       0.25   1
                  0.25   1
Name: Brand, dtype: float64
```

**Question**

How could I attache both information to the series?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If want use `value_counts` you need run code without `normalize=True`:

```
df = pd.concat([df.Brand.value_counts(normalize=True),
                df.Brand.value_counts()], 
                axis=1,
                keys=('perc','count'))
print (df)
                perc  count
                0.25      1
Honda Civic     0.25      1
Toyota Corolla  0.25      1
Audi A4         0.25      1
```

Another idea is create `perc` column in another step, [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) is for set position of new column:

```
df = df.Brand.value_counts().to_frame('count')
df.insert(0, 'perc', df['count'].div(len(df)))
         
print (df)
                perc  count
                0.25      1
Honda Civic     0.25      1
Toyota Corolla  0.25      1
Audi A4         0.25      1
```

---

```
df = df.Brand.value_counts(normalize=True).to_frame('perc')
df['count'] = df['perc'].mul(len(df))
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can try this way:

```py
pd.concat(
    [
        df.Brand.value_counts(),
        df.Brand.value_counts(normalize=True)
    ],
    keys=['counts', 'normalized_counts'],
    axis=1,
)
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.